# Chrome DevTools do not support breakpoint for public class fields(stage 3)?

Tags: reactjs, google-chrome-devtools, ecmascript-next

I followed tutorial in [React Docs: Handling Events](https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html), 
and using [public class fields syntax](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-class-fields)(which is in Stage 3 and is enabled by default in Create React App) to solve `context this` issue.

But I found that when I set a break point in Source pane, `this` is still undefined:

[image: Source pane breakpoint]

log `this` in Console is still `undefined`,

but log from the code can output the right context:

[image]

I'm curious why?

My code:

```
class App extends Component {
  handleClick = () => {
    console.log(this);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <button onClick={this.handleClick}>Click</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

npm version: 6.1.0

node version: 10.6.0

create-react-app version: 1.5.2

Comment: Problem aside: Why would or how could dev tools support something the browser itself does not support?